# GMA500 screen resolution, 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, screen, display-resolution, gma500

I have Dell Mini 1010 with GMA 500 chipset. I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 and followed instructions for sorting out distorted display/blank screen.

I am stuck with the 1024x576 screen display now.

The supported resolution for notebook is apparently 1366x768.

I have tried modifying the `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX and GRUB_GFXMODE to 1366x768x32` ( as per wiki) but it is not resolving the issue.

Can you please suggest any alternatives to fix this thing ?

Thanks

Comment: See this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/163448/fixing-800x600-resolution-in-toshiba-nb510-gma-3650-with-vesa-driver for possible things to try.

Comment: The max supported resolution for the Mini 1010 is 1024x576, give or take.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had the same problem... here is the link we used to solve it...

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

Here is th

Using any editor, create a file `/etc/grub.d/01_915resolution` , add in lines

```
echo insmod 915resolution
echo 915resolution 58 1366 768 32
Make the file executable

sudo chmod a+x /etc/grub.d/01_915resolution
```

Next, edit /etc/default/grub, assign value 1366x768x32 to variables `GRUB_GFXMODE` and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX`:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1366x768x32
Then update grub.

sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -3):

First off all try to update to the latest kernel (3.5). The new driver should fix you the resolution issue.

Comment: Don't know why there are so many downvotes to this answer, using Linux 3.5 and gma500_gfx driver solved many problems for me.